# ImportError: DLL load failed - when trying to import spynner

Tags: python, import, spynner

When I run a code which imports `spynner`, I get the following error:

```
> python .\spynner-test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\spynner-test.py", line 10, in <module>
    import spynner
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spynner\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from browser import *
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spynner\browser.py", line 56, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtNetwork import QNetworkCookie, QNetworkAccessManager, QSslConfiguration, QSslCipher
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

A funny thing is that I can import those things in normal python shell without any problem:

```
> python
Python 2.7.5 |Anaconda 1.9.2 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  1 2013, 12:37:52) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt4.QtNetwork import QNetworkCookie, QNetworkAccessManager, QSslConfiguration, QSslCipher
>>>
```

But after `import spynner` fails,

```
> python
Python 2.7.5 |Anaconda 1.9.2 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  1 2013, 12:37:52) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import spynner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spynner\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from browser import *
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spynner\browser.py", line 56, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtNetwork import QNetworkCookie, QNetworkAccessManager, QSslConfiguration, QSslCipher
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
>>> from PyQt4.QtNetwork import QNetworkCookie, QNetworkAccessManager, QSslConfiguration, QSslCipher
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. The problem is that spynner first tries to import `PySide`, and it gets an error in importing `QSslConfiguration` from `PyQt4.QtNetwork`. And then it switches to `PyQt4`, and apparently the previously imported `PySide` makes the PyQt4 import fail. When I remove the `try:` part in `browser.py` I could import `spynner` fine.